# W-shingling implementation - storing shingles

Tags: java

I need to implement [w-shingling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling) (in Java) to compare similirarity of two html documents. The question is how to gather and store shingles. Let's assume that (a,rose,is,a,rose,is,a,rose) is one of these documents. I guess that my alorithm (with LinkedList) won't be the fastest:

1. Get next single word from document (a) - if there are no other words, stop here.
2. Check (a) occurency in shingles list
3. If it occurs there, go to first step
4. If it isn't, attach it to the list and go to the first step

As I predict, this could be extremeally slow with large documents. Can you give me some hints to make it faster...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the algorithm you must first create all possible w-shinglings - *w*-length word sequences occurring in a document. You need to maintain a window of *w*-length sequence of words read from document (i.e. after reading *w* + 1 word you may discard the first word in buffer).

For storing w-shingling you could create immutable class and implement [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) to improve comparison performance. As you build the shinglings you can store them in a `Set` to get rid of duplicates on the fly.